# Determining the Length and Width of Objects in an Image with Java

Tags: java, width, shapes, detection

I want to be able to determine the length and width of all shapes in an image with a transparent background. Can anyone give me some tips in java on how to do this?

Here is an example

[image]

Edit: All pixels within each shape do not have the exact same RGB value, however, they are shades of the same color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on what you are starting with and how you define length and width.  Image analysis is a large field, and there are several nice image analysis packages/libraries written in Java (have a look at http://imagej.nih.gov/ij/ and http://fiji.sc/ImgLib2).

However, if you have access to the RGB values of your image, all pixels in each structure have the exact same RGB value, and you are interested in finding the width and length of the bounding box of the structures in your image, then you can iterate through the x and y coordinates of the image an keep track of the minimum and maximum x and y coordinate for each RGB value.  The difference between minimum and maximum in x will give the width, and in y will give you the height.

Comment: All pixels in each structure do not have the exact same RGB value, however, they are shades of the same color.

Comment: How would you go about keeping track of the minimum and maximum x and y coordinate?

Comment: As long as you can identify, based on RGB value, to which "shade of the same color" the pixels belong, you can use the approach mentioned in the answer.  To keep track of the minimum and maximum x and y, do something like:  minxRed = img.width+1; minyRed = img.height+1; maxxRed = 0; maxyRed = 0; then cycle through x and y separately, if pixel is red compare x with minxRed and maxxRed and change those when needed, same for y.